# Evaluating the integral $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x^2)\arctan(x^2)dx}{1+x^2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x^2)\arctan(x^2)dx}{1+x^2}$$

I couldn't think of much except taking $x=\tan(t)$ which reduced the integral to $$\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln(\sec^2(t))\arctan(\tan^2(t))dt$$

Which still doesn't looks good to me.

Taking $\arctan(x^2)=t$ doesn't help much either. Neither does $\ln(1+x^2)=t$

Comment: Why do you think this has a nice answer? Where did you find it?

Comment: To be honest, my friend gave me this. Firstly I spent time on this myself, then decided to post here. It might aswell be true that it doesn't have a nice answer but Wolfram returned a value of 0.8

Comment: $\arctan(\tan^2(t))=-\arctan(\cos(2t))+\frac{\pi}{4}$ But that probably doesn't help... I think your "friend" made a mistake, this is no "fun" question to do in your sparetime ;-)

Comment: have you tried uv method?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is not $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x^2)\arctan(x)dx}{1+x^2}$ instead ?

Comment: Are you sure that your friend is ..... a friend ?

Comment: Maybe considering $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x^2)\arctan\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)dx}{1+x^2}$